# Error on getting ressult from different tabs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have to access some site contents ,but on scraping it with using beautiful soup i found this error None type

```
#parsing the url
import urllib2, sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

site= "http://www.doctoralia.com.au/healthpros"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
last_page = soup.find('li', class_='last').a
```

This is giving an error in return

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "srapping1.py", line 10, in <module>
last_page = soup.find('li', class_='last').a
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'
```

Comment: It means `last_page` is `None`, which in turn means `soup.find` didn't find anything on the page and returned `None`.

Comment: you have used "class_" in find method. Is it intentional or you meant "class" there?

Comment: I am using `bs4` 4.3.1 and `soup.find('li', attrs={'class':'last'})` can find the target element in your page.

Comment: NoneType means that instead of an instance of whatever Class or Object you think you're working with, you've actually got None. That usually means that an assignment or function call up above failed or returned an unexpected result.

Comment: @user2109788 i have used it intentionally,do you have any idea how to get the last tab link i have got it form here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842052/get-data-form-different-urls

Comment: @user2109788: yes, that is intentional, provided you use BeautifulSoup 4 however. `class` is a reserved keyword in Python, you cannot use it as an argument in a function call, so the BeautifulSoup project supports `class_` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using BeautifulSoup version 3, but tried to use syntax only supported by BeautifulSoup *version 4*.

You'd have to pass in the class attribute query as a dictionary instead:

```
soup.find('li', {'class':'last'})
```

Not that that returns a pager element; you'd want to look for `ul.pager` first:

```
last_page = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'pager'}).find('li', {'class': 'last'}).a
```

Demo:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
>>> soup.find('li', {'class':'last'})
<li class="last">Medical practice</li>
>>> soup.find('ul', {'class': 'pager'}).find('li', {'class': 'last'})
<li class="last"><a href="/healthpros/1563">1563</a></li>
```

You really should upgrade to BeautifulSoup 4 however, version 3 hasn't seen a new release in over 2 years.

Even better, BeautifulSoup 4 support [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
last_page = soup.select('ul.pager li.last a')[0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
>>> soup.select('ul.pager li.last a')[0]
<a href="/healthpros/1563">1563</a>
```

Comment: You have mentioned it several times before,but always i run into this ,i have switched it to version 4 and it is working fine,i've remembered it after psoting the question,soory

Comment: @FazeelaAbuZohra: but yeah, I cannot remember everyone I've told this to, so you got told again. :-) If you uninstalled BeautifulSoup 3 perhaps the import error will remind you next time? :-P

Answer (score 0):

It's because `soup.find('li', class_='last')` can't find nothing so it returns `None` (just try to use `print soup.find('li', class_='last')` and you will see this result) so a NoneObject doesn't have the `a` method, in other words find method is not matching any criteria.